# Can the Socratic method be used to teach science or math?

Tags: socrates

I'm not sure if this is philosophy or pedagogy, because it kind of straddles both!

I've seen this method used for extremely abstract problems in philosophy. But I haven't seen it used for resolving confused beliefs regarding something in science.

Can a good science or math instructor use the Socratic method to resolve difficulties in a student's understanding of a concept in science or math?

Comment: Yes, but. Riffel explains in [The Socratic Method Reloaded](https://ir.canterbury.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/10092/11826/12655161_CLR%20version%2C%20final.pdf?sequence=2):"*Importantly,  the  Socratic  method  works  best  with  open-ended  questions  (not  yes/no  questions),  although  it  has  also  been  used  to  teach maths  in  elementary  school*". A reference for the latter is [Garlikov](http://www.studygs.net/teaching/crtthkc.htm). [Moore method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_method) in advanced math is in a similar spirit, although I wouldn't call it "Socratic" exactly.

Comment: Related [Can mathematics be learned by ONLY solving problems?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/12476/4621) on Math Ed SE. More generally, [student-centered learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student-centred_learning), [inquiry-based learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquiry-based_learning) (promoted by Dewey),  "guide on the side, not sage on the stage" teaching, [flipped classrooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipped_classroom) can be broadly seen as the modern descendants of the Socratic method, and are employed in teaching science and math, among other subjects.

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we learn math and science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/44947/how-do-we-learn-math-and-science)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*Meno*](http://classics.mit.edu/Plato/meno.html) is one of the original Platonic dialogues that introduces the Socratic Method explicitly as a pedagogical technique.  In it, the example use of the method is to teach --or as Plato prefers to conceptualize it, induce recollection of-- mathematics, specifically geometry.

In addition to demonstrating the method itself, it also shows how it could be used in a mathematical context.

When in doubt, go back to the original source!